# classe preencher tabela feita na classe DAO

Tags: java, jtable

Pessoal estou meio enrolado e agradeceria a ajuda.

O projeto funciona, insere usuários no banco de dados, mas eu gostaria de fazer uma jtable para exibir os dados inseridos;

Aqui o projeto completo(Estou tendo dificuldade de postar aqui
https://www.sendspace.com/file/awfigd

```
 SQL:

    create database projetojava; 
    use projetojava;
    CREATE TABLE usuario ( 
    id BIGINT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    nome VARCHAR(255), 
    cpf VARCHAR(255), 
    email VARCHAR(255),
    telefone VARCHAR(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) );

    select * from usuario;

    Pacote DAO (Ao qual pretendo criar um método preencherTabela() )


        package dao;
```

Comment: Faça um [tour] para entender melhor como funciona o Stack Overflow. Veja também como criar um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Baixar seu projeto para identificar o problema e dar uma resposta é inviável para esse tipo de comunidade, fora que a resposta servirá somente para você, tente tornar sua pergunta [relevante para outros usuários](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) também.

Comment: Sua pergunta tem sérios problemas. Primeiro que ela é muito vaga e genérica, pois pede para "*fazer uma jtable para exibir os dados inseridos*", sendo que deve ter umas milhões de formas diferentes de fazer isso. Depois, colocar o link para baixar o projeto inteiro não é legal. O legal é minimizar o seu problema para ficar mais fácil de se resolver. Veja sobre [mcve].